# Installing a Java Dev Kit

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I am fairly new to ubuntu.
I am trying to find a package for the Java JDK to use javac and the other compiler utils included in the JRE.

I cannot however seem to be able to install them (either package not found or not installable).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 17.04, the command will be `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` or `sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk`  There are not packages in the current universe for jdk 6 and 7

Comment: what is the difference between those packages and `sudo apt-get install default-jdk` or `jre`? Is that one just the "open source" version of the Oracle JDK/JRE? @CharlesGreen

Comment: One the the *J*ava *D*evelopment *K*it, the other is the *J*ava *R*untime *E*nvironment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option would be to install the default version that available on Ubuntu package list, you can choose either to install Java Dev Kit (JDK) or Java Runtime Environment (JRE):

1. First, update the package index

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. To install Java Dev Kit (JDK), run following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install default-jdk
   ```

   Above command will install JDK, but if you instead want to install JRE

   ```
   sudo apt-get install default-jre
   ```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to make sure your package index is up to date before you try to install anything :-

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install the Java JDK with

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

There are TWO Ways you can do this.

You can download the JDK package from Oracle itself. Here is the link - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Get the variant you want. Then run the following commands to actually extract it and use it.

First, you need to extract the archive using `tar` The file will be called "AutoDL BundleID=" or similar.

```
tar xzf <name of file>
```

This will create a folder called jdk-8u1 or similar. This can be copied to `/usr/local`. Next you will need to add this folder to your $PATH so other programs can invoke it.

Assuming you copied to /usr/local, run this command to add to $PATH

```
PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin
```

You must also open your `/home/user/.bashrc` file and add this line before the final `fi` so it will always be exported before your shell seesion starts.

Now you can use java/javac for whatever you need.